# Ошибка, TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

Всем привет!
Создаю свое первое приложение на Django.
Пытаюсь вызвать простое отображение, но отлавливаю проблему:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def start(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

urls.py

```
from os import path
from parus.views import *


urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', start),
]
```

Сам проект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пжста разобраться чем вызвана такая ошибка, код элементарный, а вот запустить не выходит.
Ах да, я новичок в python:)

Добавлю стэк ошибки:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\averi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\averi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\averi\PycharmProjects\eisparus\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\averi\PycharmProjects\eisparus\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\averi\PycharmProjects\eisparus\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\averi\PycharmProjects\eisparus\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\averi\PycharmProjects\eisparus\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\averi\PycharmProjects\eisparus\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\averi\PycharmProjects\eisparus\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\averi\PycharmProjects\eisparus\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\averi\PycharmProjects\eisparus\eisparus\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    from parus import urls
  File "C:\Users\averi\PycharmProjects\eisparus\parus\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    path('index/', start),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Пишите полный стек ошибки, а то сложно понять где именно проблема. Но в вашем случае, это похоже с `from os import path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас тут неправильный импорт из `os` сущности `path`:

```
from os import path
from parus.views import *


urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', start),
]
```

У джанго [path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urls/#path) берется импортом из этого модуля:

```
from django.urls import path
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло. Хотел бы еще уточнить, вот стэк ошибки, на что нужно обращать внимание?

Comment: @ЮрийАверьянов, на последнюю строку - там указано место в коде где была ошибка: `File "C:\Users\averi\PycharmProjects\eisparus\parus\urls.py", line 6, in <module> path('index/', start),`. Тут видно, что ошибка была с `path` в файле `...\eisparus\parus\urls.py` в строке 6. А ошибка `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` означает что к тому объекту применили круглые скобки

Comment: Грубо говоря, вызывать объекты как функции можно, но для этого нужно определить магический метод `__call__` и с модулями это можно, если применить хитрость: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6b9269f6363bdfda73052cf1d932272c7cd98cc7/Callable%20modules/main.py#L8 . Но этого на практике не видел :)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я создал еще один вопрос, может сможете помочь?:) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1490292/%d0%a8%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0

Comment: @ЮрийАверьянов, посмотреть-то посмотрю, но я больше по фласку, чем по джанго :)