# "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python

не судите строго, только начал учить python ошибка: "dp = dispatcher(bot)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" в коде

```
import openai
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

token = "token"
openai.api_key = "token"

bot = Bot(token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def send(message : types.Message):
    response = openai.completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-003",
        promt=message.text,
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=1000,
        top_p=1.0,
        frequency_penalty=0.5,
        presence_penalty=0.0,
    )

    await message.answer(response['choices'][0]['text'])

executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit]). И подправьте код в вопросе - он разъехался и стал невалидным

Comment: Оффтоп. Забавно. Вчера был подобный вопрос, но по django: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1489651/201445 . Но там такие же требования: стек ошибки, чтобы понять в каком месте она возникла. И решение: использование правильного импорта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Но `dispatcher` - это действительно модуль, как и написано в ошибке. Вероятно, вы хотели создать объект `Dispatcher`:

```py
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
                               ^^^^^^^^^^ с большой буквы!!
    ...
    bot = Bot(token)
    dp = Dispatcher(bot)
         ^^^^^^^^^^ с большой буквы!!
```